# How to access backbone view in submitHandler callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm exploring backbone.js and I'm trying to setup simple login page. Here is my view.js file:

```
window.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({   

    events: {

    },

    initialize : function() {       
        this.model.bind("error", this.error);       
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('login'));       
    },  

    login: function(form){
        this.model.set({
            login: $("#login", form).val(),
            password: $("#password", form).val()
        });         
    },  

    render : function(eventName) {      
        $(this.el).html(this.template());   
        $(this.el).find("form").validate({
            submitHandler: this.login
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

As you can see I use `jquery.validation` attached to form in `render` function. As submitHandler callback I've set `login` function. This line

```
this.model.set({...
```

is giving me `this.model is undefined` error so I assume that `this` in login function is not the same as `this` in `initialize` or `render` functions. My question how I can access backbone `this` in login function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use jQuery.proxy() to set the value of "this" for the login function:

```
$(this.el).find("form").validate({
  submitHandler: $.proxy(this.login, this)
});
```

Proxy returns a new function with a new value for "this". Since "this" in the render function points to your view, you pass it as the second argument to proxy.

Comment: thanks ;) I came up with something using tmp variable assigned with backbone `this` but your solution is much more elegant :)

Comment: I think bind is preferred to proxy these days, but this helps - thanks!

Comment: yeah if you don't need to worry about old browsers : this.login.bind(this)